# To get the list of albums from dbpedia using SURF dbpedia library

Tags: python, rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to run a sample code of SURF Dbpedia from this https://pythonhosted.org/SuRF/examples/dbpedia.html

```
import surf
store = surf.Store(reader = 'sparql_protocol',
                   endpoint = 'http://dbpedia.org/sparql',
                   default_graph = 'http://dbpedia.org')

print 'Create the session'
session = surf.Session(store, {})
session.enable_logging = False
PhilCollinsAlbums = session.get_class(surf.ns.YAGO['PhilCollinsAlbums'])
all_albums = PhilCollinsAlbums.all()
print 'Phil Collins has %d albums on dbpedia' % len(all_albums)
```

It is giving **an error** :

```
Create the session
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nitin/surf/sample.py", line 16, in <module>
    print 'Phil Collins has %d albums on dbpedia' % len(all_albums)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SuRF-1.1.4_r352-py2.7.egg/surf/resource/result_proxy.py", line 231, in __len__
    _, get_by_response = self.__execute_get_by()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SuRF-1.1.4_r352-py2.7.egg/surf/resource/result_proxy.py", line 211, in __execute_get_by
    self.__get_by_response = store.get_by(self.__get_by_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SuRF-1.1.4_r352-py2.7.egg/surf/store.py", line 182, in get_by
    return self.reader.get_by(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SuRF-1.1.4_r352-py2.7.egg/surf/plugin/reader.py", line 149, in get_by
    return self._get_by(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SuRF-1.1.4_r352-py2.7.egg/surf/plugin/query_reader.py", line 213, in _get_by
    for match in table:
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: The combination of `len(all_albums)` and `TypeError: iteration over non-sequence` would lead me to guess that `all_albums` isn't a sequence.  What do you get if you just, e.g., print it?

Comment: Thanks for responding sir. After printing `all_albums`, it is giving output `surf.resource.result_proxy.ResultProxy object at 0xa3a436c>.` I know `all_albums is an object`, I can't iterate over it. I had also converted the object into list in python using list(all_albums) but even though it was giving the same error.

Comment: Any chance you're running an old version or something?  The source at https://pythonhosted.org/SuRF/_modules/surf/resource/result_proxy.html does show an `__iterator` method.  I'm not much of a Pythonista though, so I can't tell you whether that should be enough or not.